# How to migrate 'displayfeatures' and 'ec' plugins requirements from react-ga to react-ga4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, react-ga

Because of the upcoming GA4, we will start using react-ga4 instead of react-ga. And we have these lines in our code for the GA initialization from the react-ga.

```
ReactGA.plugin.require('displayfeatures');
ReactGA.plugin.require('ec');
```

I couldn't find how to use them with react-ga4. Do you know how can we use them?

Note: We use the `ec` for `ec:addImpression`. Sending an impression is a bit different in GA4 & react-ga4. We send it with `React.GA.event(....)` now. Maybe we don't need the `ec` plugin at all but tbh I don't know if we're doing it correctly or not. It would have been nice to get some ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GA 4, sending [recommended events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735) is how you go about measuring user interaction on your e-commerce website.

You can map these events to their [EC plugin counterparts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-activities) for backward compatibility.

The `view_item` event takes the place of `ec:addImpression` and [item parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events#view_item) can be readily mapped to [impression data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#impression-data).

The features enabled formerly via the `displayfeatures` plugin are enabled when `ReactGA` initializes your gtag property.
This is because the default value for the [`allowAdFeatures` option is enabled](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#allowAdFeatures).

You don't have to make any changes there. However, you can enable those features explicitly by writing,

```
ReactGA.initialize([
  {
    trackingId: "your GA measurement id",
    gtagOptions: {
      allowAdFeatures: true
    },
  },
]);
```

or temporarily ad-hoc enable them and disable them

```
ReactGA.set('allowAdFeatures', true);
// send some hits
ReactGA.set('allowAdFeatures', false);
```